# Thymeleaf HTML5 long variable issue

Tags: html, spring-boot, long-integer, thymeleaf

I am new to Thymeleaf and HTML5.

I have a variable `order number` of data type `long`.

There is an input text field in the HTML for searching order number (assigned to `order number` variable), which always initialise to zero everytime when we load the HTML page.

Also, I am getting the error when I manually empty the filed and submit the form to fetch record from database.

My requirement is to have this field empty because this is an optional field. It can be zero/null/doesn’t contain any value.

Sample Code Snippet: `<input type=“text” th:field=${order.ordernumber}>`

Please advise on how to get this order number variable (`long` data type) without any default value being set.

Comment: You don't actually have your code snippet in there :-)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for notifying. Below is the sample code snippet. <input type=“text” th:field=${order.ordernumber}> Could you please assist on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your model. If there is `0` and this is the default for `long` this will shown in the view. If the ordernumber can be null or empty you should use `Long`.
This is only an assumption. To give you a detailed answer you must provide more information.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. Yes, my order number can be empty. I'll try using Long.

Comment: If you accept and upvote the answer you help other person and you will get more answers in the future.

Comment: I accept the answer but I couldn't able to vote up. I joined the forum recently and it says no enough reputation

Comment: Ok upvote could be difficult. Accept should work. The answer get the a check mark.